# Library semPlot load failed

Tags: semplot

When I tried to run the library(semPlot) , always receive an error message:

> library(semPlot)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘semPlot’:
>    objeto ‘readPNG’ não foi exportado por 'namespace:png'

Besides when I run the function sem Paths another error :

> Error in semPaths(fit, title = FALSE, sizeMan = 4, sizeMan2 = 4, sizeLat = 4,  : 
>     could not find function "semPaths"

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem as follows:

1. Install semPlot using `install.packages("semPlot")`
2. Wait for the dependencies to install
3. Restart R
4. Invoke the install command again using `install.packages("semPlot")`

I found that this installed two remaining libraries (`XML` and `semPlot`) and I was able to continue my analysis.